# Would the name Maida be considered a “Japanese name”

Tags: kanji

A friend of mine is named Maida (female), and it got me thinking...since the name Maeda is a japanese name, and has it’s own Kanji, would Maida (spelled with an i) be a japanese name? And does it have it’s own Kanji?

I searched 毎田 and it turns out that an old japanese buddhist thinker by the name Maida did exist...a guy (lol) but that doesn’t matter.

Anyways, would Maida be considered a japanese name and is the kanji; 毎田 even something that sounds remotely right?

Thanks!

Comment: http://jisho.org/search/%23names%20maida

Comment: Strange question. You don't indicate whether it is a given name or a surname. You also don't indicate your friend's ethnic history, which makes a big difference (Japanese-Brazilians change spellings, for example). It would be apropos to include your purpose in trying to kanjify the name.

Comment: Maida is also a name in Spanish. However, it's not clear why you're trying to find if the name could be a name in Japanese unless you're trying to find out something more specific, like, how to write it, in which case you'd ask this friend (supposing they are Japanese and know the correct Kanji to their name). Otherwise, the question seems to me like you'd like to Japan-ify someone's name, in which case I suggest using Katakana instead.

Answer (score 4):

Maida does not sound weird as a **surname / family name**, but it's fairly rare and I personally know no one with that name. I don't know how you came up with 毎田, but "Maida" could also be 舞田, 真井田, 米田, 馬出 and so on.

As a given name, it sounds peculiar to me. Do you understand Japanese family names come before given names? 毎田 is the **family name** of [this Buddhist thinker](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AF%8E%E7%94%B0%E5%91%A8%E4%B8%80).

Comment: Would you really read 米田 as 「まいだ」 instead of 「よねだ」?  I guess, but it sounds odd.

Comment: It's not uncommon for a kanji family name to have more than one possible readings. Most people will read 米田 as よねだ if there was no furigana, I think.

Comment: I know only two people with that name, and it was まいださん　and こもださん. There's another one at work who I have never met but the 名簿 says よねだ.

Answer (score 0):

I am Japanese liveing 40+years. I never have met Maida-san for her Family Name before. But it sound comfortable to me.